# A generalisation of a well known result in information theory

Tags: information-theory

It is well known that Entropy is additive, and that it is the only sensible choice for measuring uncertainty if we want additivity to hold, i.e.

$H(XY) = H(X)+H(Y)$

or more explicitly, if we have the constraint that

$\int_\chi\int_\chi p_1(x)p_2(x) f(p_1(x)p_2(x)) dx^2 = \int_\chi p_1(x) f(p_1(x)) dx + \int_\chi p_2(x) f(p_2(x))dx$

with $\int_\chi p_1 dx = \int_\chi p_2 dx = 1$. The only choice is $f(u) = k \log(u)$.

There is a similar problem concerning f-divergences, where we can introduce an additivity constraint:

$\int_\chi\int_\chi p_1(x)p_2(x) f\left(\frac{p_1(x)p_2(x)}{q_1(x)q_2(x)}\right) dx^2 = \int_\chi p_1(x) f\left(\frac{p_1(x)}{q_1(x)}\right) dx + \int_\chi p_2(x) f\left(\frac{p_2(x)}{q_2(x)}\right)dx$

I am pretty sure that the only valid functions $f$ are

$f(u) = (A/u+B)\log(u)$

but I do not know how to show that (or even if) this exhausts all the possibilities.

**EDIT:**

Corrected u to 1/u, to fit the definition of $u = p/q$ (usually it is $q/p$).

**How I get to** $(\frac{A}{u}+B)\log(u)$

First of all, if $f(u)$ and $g(u)$ are solutions, so is their linear combination: $a f(u) + b g(u)$. I can find two solutions that are not linearly related

1) $f(u) = k_1 \log u$

2) $f(u) = k_2 \frac{\log u}{u}$  (this effectively switches p and q)

these can be shown to work, making all the solutions of the form I proposed valid as they are linear combinations of (1) and (2). The problem I have is that I am not sure that there are not other functions that are not linearly related to either (1) or (2).

Comment: $f$-diverence is usually defined as $D_f(p|q)=\int q(x) f\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)dx$ with $f$ strictly convex, $f(1)=0$ and $0\cdot f(0/0)=0$.

Comment: yes, but I'm not so fussed about the convexity, especially its strictness. Though if there is a proof that uses it, that is better than nothing.

Comment: @Ashok fixed upside down fraction for you :) well, made what I said consistent with it being upside down.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**
With due permission I am completely rewriting the proof.

Let $$D_f(P|Q)=\sum_i p_if(q_i/p_i)$$ where $f$ is a strictly convex function such that $f(1)=0$, satisfy additivity, i.e., $D_f(P_1\star P_2|Q_1\star Q_2)=D_f(P_1|Q_1)+D_f(P_2|Q_2)$ with $D_f((1,0)|(1/2,1/2))=1$, where $P\star Q$ is the product distribution, i.e., $(p_iq_j)_{i,j}$.

This proof is just a by product of [Renyi](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/berkeley-symposium-on-mathematical-statistics-and-probability/Proceedings-of-the-Fourth-Berkeley-Symposium-on-Mathematical-Statistics-and/chapter/On-Measures-of-Entropy-and-Information/bsmsp/1200512181)'s work.

Let $ P_1=P_2=(1,0),Q_1=(q_1,1-q_1), Q_2=(q_2,1-q_2)$.

Then $D_f(P_1\star P_2|Q_1\star Q_2)=f(q_1q_2)$, $D_f(P_1|Q_1)=f(q_1)$, and $D_f(P_2|Q_2)=f(q_2)$

So by additivity, $f(q_1q_2)=f(q_1)+f(q_2)$. And from $D_f((1,0)|(1/2,1/2))=1$, $f(1/2)=1$. Also from Jensen's inequality $D_f(P|Q)\ge f(1)=0$, hence $f$ is non negative.

The only $f$ satisfying the above three properties is $f(q)=-\log q$ and we are done.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you have done here. I take it ${1}$ and ${1/2}$ are unnormalised probability distributions. I'll add what I have done so far to my question.

Comment: @Lucas: Yes I admit that the solution I have given is not very correct. I do not claim that I have given a correct solution. When someone gives a correct solution I will delete this. I am also working on this to make this very rigorous and correct. I am sure that we should proceed along this line. This was (still, it is) my opinion after I went through Renyi's paper. By this $D_f(\{1\}|\{1/2\})$, I mean $D_f((1,0)|(1/2,1/2))$. This is just a boundary condition to get the exact solution $f(p)=-\log p$ which Renyi also has in some other form.

Comment: I was just trying to understand it.